# Aplicação Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, if

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que é um dicionário de acordes para violão. E como são inúmeros acordes, consequentemente tenho inúmeras Activities. O problema é que o aplicativo ficará muito, mas muito grande, por conta de estar usando os botões e imagens diversas vezes, por exemplo: Se tenho 200 acordes, tenho 200 activities e estou usando as mesmas imagens e botoes por 200 vezes. Para solucionar o problema, pensei em usar uma Activity "genérica", ou seja, a mesma para todos os acordes. Deste modo, quando eu escolher o acorde Dó, a Activity se comportara de um jeito (os botoes que simulam os dedos ficarão em uma determinada posição), e quando eu escolher o acorde ré, esta mesma Activity se comportará de outro modo (os botoes mudaram novamente). Isso é possível pessoal???

Answer (score 0):

É possível se a casca for a mesma, e os botões virarem imagens. Dai é só chamar através do banco o nome da imagem.

Recomendo pesquisar sobre RecyclerView, ItemView, Biblioteca Picasso (Para carregar as imagens) e como armazenar utilizando um banco de dados no Android.